# return false BindService in api 30

Tags: android, android-intent, serviceconnection, bindservice

when i run my code with compileSdkVersion 30 doesn't work but in 29 code working

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setPackage("com.androidlearn.securityman");

ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        Log.e("","");
        Toast.makeText(context,"onServiceConnected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        listener.onSuccess(IPaymentInterface.Stub.asInterface(service));
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        Toast.makeText(context,"onServiceDisconnected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.e("","");
        listener.onFailure("connection failed");

    }
};
context.bindService(intent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

}

In api 30 bindService return false and serviceConnection doesn't respond to listeners

How to solve this problem ?

Comment: There are some differences about how to use Foreground Services on Android 11...you can start from there.

Comment: I just use binder ipc not Foreground Services

Comment: Is "context" valid and alive when you call "bindService"? If you try to bind to Service from a stopped/finished Activity, it will returns FALSE.

Comment: yes, activity is running. problem is just on api 30 and below version dosen't have any problem

Answer (score 4):

It might be related to the package visibility settings introduced in Android 11. When you have 2 apps: **server** with the service you are exposing and **client** that wants to bind that service - the client needs to declare in its Manifest that it can use the service package, like:

```
<manifest package="com.example.game">
    <queries>
        <package android:name="com.example.store" />
        <package android:name="com.example.services" />
    </queries>
    ...
</manifest>
```

Otherwise binding will return false, and in system-wide Logcat you will see something like:

```
I/AppFilter: Interaction: PackageSetting {<client.app.package/PID> -> <server.app.package/PID>} Blocked
W/ActivityManager: Unable to start service Intent { act=<action> pkg=<server.app.package>} U=0: not found
```

Because without this Manifest declaration the server app service is invisible for client app. Its still possible to start it from the `adb` if you want to check if the intent data is correct.

More info: https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/declaring